# Finding number of combinations of numbers from multiple arrays that add up to a given value

Tags: algorithms, arrays, efficiency, knapsack-problems, subset-sum

Let $ A $ be an array of $ n $ integer arrays with unknown lengths and $ s \in \mathbb{Z} $ a  given number. I want to find the number of combinations of numbers from each array, such that their sum is $ s $. In set theory terms, if I have $ n $ tuples, $ A_1, A_2, \ldots A_n $, I want to find all $ (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n) \in \times_{k=1}^{n} A_k$ such that $ sum((a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_2)) = s $. I tried to do so by first finding the cartesian product of all the arrays, and then iterating every combination and checking its sum. The problem is that even if I have only $ 10 $ arrays with $ 10 $ elements each, the cartesian product's length would be $ 10000000000 $, which could even be too much for the browser (I'm writing it in the browser with JS) to handle, and I would have to do $ 10000000000 $ iterations, not including iterating every combination. Is there any known and more efficient algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Do you want to list them all, or count how many there are?  Is this a practical problem, or do you want to know the theoretical worst-case running time?  If it is a practical problem, can you tell us about how large $n$ is and about how large $s$ is and about how large each number is?  Can you tell us about the motivation for this problem or the context where you encountered it?

Comment: @D.W. I just want count how mamy there are. It is a practical question, $ n $ can be any number from $ 1 $ to $ 100 $, $ s $ can be any integer.

Comment: Are the numbers unique? Can the same number appear in the same array multiple times?

Comment: @NarekBojikian  It's an array, so a number can multiple times

Comment: Is there a lower and upper bound on each entry in the arrays? For example, are the numbers between -100 and 100?

Comment: @AspiringMat no

Comment: If s and the entries are unbounded, the problem is NP-hard with a reduction from 2-partition. Given an instance of two partition array X[1..n], create n arrays with with two elements each: 0 and X[i]. There is a 2 partition of X if and only if there is a solution to your problem with Sum(X)/2.

Comment: Please tell us a *typical* size for $s$ and a typical size for the numbers in the arrays.  There is no solution that will work efficiently for all sizes (this is hard in the worst case), so you'll need to give us some idea on typical sizes for us to have a hope of offering you anything useful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74033050/781723

Answer (score 1):

The problem is NP-hard.  As @AspiringMat [explains](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/154695/finding-number-of-combinations-of-numbers-from-multiple-arrays-that-add-up-to-a?noredirect=1#comment325313_154695), even to determine whether there exists any solution at all is as hard as [the partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem): given an instance of two-partition with numbers $x_1,\dots,x_n$, let the $i$th array contain $0$ and $x_i$, set $s=(x_1+\dots+x_n)/2$, and test whether there exists any solution to your problem.  Counting the number of solutions is at least as hard as determining whether there is any solution or not.

As a result, you can't expect any algorithm that will be efficient and work for all possible inputs.  Instead, you'll need to consider standard methods for dealing with intractable problems, such as focusing on a particular subset of problem instances (e.g., specify the typical size of $n$, $s$, and the integers in the arrays), or accept an exponential-time algorithm.

You can study algorithms for the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).  Some of them can be adapted to your problem -- though they might take exponential time.

The problem statement is not clear about whether you want to count how many solutions exist, or to list them all.  I am assuming above that you want to count the number of solutions.  If you want to list them all, this can take exponential time in the worst case, as there can be exponentially many solutions (consider, e.g., the case where each array contains 0 and 1, and where $s \approx n/2$).